# Apache virtual hosts on subdirectories

Tags: django, windows, virtualhost, wsgi, apache2.4

I am trying to setup Apache to serve multiple apps on one IP-Address over subdirectories. Lets say, I would like to access App1 over http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/app1 and App2 over http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/app2. Both, App1 and App2, are independent django projects. I ensured, that both apps are working fine by serving only one of them over Apache.

I added the following lines to the httpd.conf file of Apache:

```
# App1
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Projects/App1/App1"
    ServerName App1

    <Directory "D:/Projects/App1/App1">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias /app1 "D:/Projects/App1/App1/wsgi.py"
</VirtualHost>

# App2
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Projects/App2/App2"
    ServerName App2

    <Directory "D:/Projects/App2/App2">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias /app2 "D:/Projects/App2/App2/wsgi.py"
</VirtualHost>
```

Working like this results into an error saying "Forbidden, You don't have permission to access this resource." when I call http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/app2 from another machine. Similar to this, if I put the App2 virtual host in front of the App1 virtual host, I can not access http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/app1 anymore. So it is either App1 or App2 that is accessible, but never both of them.

First question: Is my idea of serving to webpages over sub-URL's even possible? If not, what would be the alternative? Using different ports for different applications? If it is a "valid" approach, why do I have access to just one but not both apps at with this configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the **VirtualHost** directive is to provide different applications based on the requested hosts.
To resolve an application based on the directory, you may use the  [Alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive instead of VirtualHost.

Comment: Thank you for the quick statement! Could you give some more information about "the directive" you wrote about?

Comment: It seems that SO parser broken some formatting. I talked about the Alias directive. I have edited my message above so you can follow the documentation link with the usage examples